# Import Oracle Database into Database Project

Tags: sql-server, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, database-project

I'd like to be able to use a Visual Studio Database Project against an Oracle server.

I can successfully connect it against an instance of SQL Server with no problems, however when I attempt to connect to Oracle the datasource button is greyed out:

[image]

I sincerely hope that it's possible to use this against Oracle.  However if not are there any alternatives / workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the following:

[Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

[Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html)

Comment: Keith, have you used that successfully? Just curious as we have some Oracle installs in our company and this could be really interesting if it works for those.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't speak from experience. I'm only aware of these tools but I've never used them.

Comment: Unfortunately I already have those installed, and can successfully connect to Oracle via Visual Studio (data sources window), @Peter Schott - I'd be interested to chat over how you maintain Oracle along with SQL server, because currently their differences are causing lots of problems.

Comment: I actually don't have anything to do with the Oracle servers. They're used to run completely different systems. That's probably the main reason we don't have that many problems. :)  I was more interested in being able to use SSDT for source control of Oracle as well as SQL Server. I have SSDT working well for SQL Server. Something similar to SSDT (or SSDT itself) would be great for Oracle DB Version Control.

Comment: @PeterSchott - that's exactly the issue I'm trying to resolve, I wish Oracle just wasn't so awkward!